# Calculus - can I do this?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Apologies if this is a dumb question. I learned at school that I can differentiate $$y=x^{2}$$
 to give $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x.$$
 But, if I have a multivariable function, for example$$y=4x^{2}+3z+t^{3}$$
 am I allowed to differentiate it to give$$dy=8x\;dx+3\;dz+3t^{2}\;dt$$
 and, if valid, what is this procedure called exactly?

Thank you

Comment: Look up "partial derivatives".

Comment: That's the [differential of the function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is valid and is called the [differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function) of a function. In the link is the wikipedia page on this concept!

Consider the function, $$y=f(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$$

Goursat, a French Mathematician introduced the concept of partial differential of $y$, say, with respect to $x_i$.

A partial differential of $y$ with respect to $x_i$ is given by, $$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}\cdot \mathrm{d}x_i$$

A total differential is the sum of the partial differentials of all the independent variables. So, it is the following,

$$\mathrm{d}y=\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}\cdot\mathrm{d}x_i$$

Comment: Thanks - is that the same as the the "total differential"? It seems to be from the Wikipedia link.

Comment: Yes, what you have shown us is in fact the total differential. I'll edit to add this!

Comment: Also, you wrote "partial differential of y, say, with respect to $y_i$". I assume you meant $x_i$.

Comment: @cohen Fixed. Thanks!